# lubuntu 16.10 fails to boot after clean usb install

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, lubuntu

I'm reviving an old desktop that was strugling with win7 (Dell PW360, pentium 4 @ 3.20 GHz, 1.5 GB RAM, nvidia quadro FX 600).

The USB install using default settings failed, but after some research I suspected that nomodeset should be activated, and the install worked just fine.
However, after booting the system is unusable, with several symptoms mentioned here: [Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics)

I have a blank (white) screen, that flickers, with items displayed incorrectly.

The problem is I can't get to a working TTY. CTRL-ALT-F1 seems to work, but all I get is a white screen with nonsense characters. I managed to enter user/pass, but can't proceed entering commands "in the dark".

The sugested workaround (nouveau.modeset=0) didn't work for me, I always get a white flickering screen with nonsense characters.

Can you help me ? All I have now is a bricked desktop...

[edit: link corrected]

Comment: The link is dead. Please explain the issues.

Comment: I think you need nomodeset also in the installed system. See this link, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808. Try also to install an nvidia proprietary driver (after using nomodeset to get some working graphics). - I suggest that you try with the following versions of Lubuntu (try them live before trying to install), 14.04.1 LTS, 14.04.5 LTS, 16.04.1 LTS and 16.04.2 LTS. I can run them (and I prefer 16.04.1 LTS) in an old Dell Dimension 4600 with pentium 4 @ 2.8 GHz, 1.5 GB RAM, and nvidia NV34 [GeForce FX 5200] graphics.

Comment: Sorry about the dead link. Here it is: http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics

Comment: Thanks @sudodus. nomodeset is active in the installed system, I guess it propagates after I set it on the USB install. That's the root of my problem, even with nomodeset on I can't get a working TTY that allows me to follow the workarounds proposed.

Comment: Please try with older (but still maintained) versions of Lubuntu - old hardware <---> old software.

Comment: Tried 16.04.1 LTS (live run fails with or w/o nomodeset). Tried 14.04.5 LTS (live run with nomodeset runs) so I installed 14.04.5 with nomodeset. Installation performs ok, but after boot I get the exact same result as with 16.10 (white screen, no access to working TTY). This is clearly a video driver related problem. Is there a way I can use a proprietary/updated driver during USB install ?

Comment: Do not try 14.04.5 as that contains 14.04 with the graphics drivers from 16.04. I would try 14.04.1

Comment: Yes, I agree. It is time to try 14.04.1 LTS now.

Answer (score 0):

After reading an old post about problems related with DVI vs VGA output it hit me: 10 years ago I connected the monitor with a DVI cable (and totaly forgot about it).

I changed the monitor connection to good old VGA et voila, now it works.

Thanks for the tips guys, I hope this info helps someone.